# paging 2 grids in one page

Tags: asp.net, gridview, paging

I have 2 gridviews in 1 page and i want to enable paging in them.
now, when I want to page the first gridview to its second page, I see Its second page
but the second grid view disappears.

what am I missing?

thanks.

Comment: please post some code and markup, it´s difficult to give a general answer

Answer (score 0):

<sub>*Posted on behalf of the OP, the answer was left as a comment on the question*</sub>

I found the answer. when pressing 2, for example, to go to the 2nd page of 1 grid, a postback is occuring. on the Page_Load event I binded the sources to the grids only if page is not post back and thats why on of the grids disappeared all the time.